# User login with session variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm performing a user authentication from a file on a local computer to a remote computer via cross domain. The authentication work right but its not able to set a session variable on the remote computer to display user details. When you enter the correct email and password it tells  its logging in and it does but fails to bring the user details. When i log on to the remote computer (http://example.com/login.php) and i log in its able to bring me the details of the log on user but fails on work on the cross domain

```
$("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://example/login_script.php",
        data: data,
 success: function(data) {
    $('#log_msg').html(data);
    var result = $.trim(data);
       if(result==="Logging In"){
       window.location = 'details.html'
```

any help

Answer (score 0):

use this super jquery plugin for CORS.

this plugin change your basic jquery ajax requests and set correct headers.

https://github.com/dkastner/jquery.iecors